# Difference in usage between "ostensive" and "ostensible"

Tags: meaning, differences, confusables

I know that *ostensive* and *ostensible* are both adjectives, but can someone give me proper usage of each in their adjective forms?  In their adverb forms, they almost sound identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary.com provides a sufficient starting point:

> ***[Ostensible:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ostensible)***

> **1.** outwardly appearing as such; professed; pretended: *an ostensible cheerfulness concealing sadness.*
> **2.** apparent, evident, or conspicuous: *the ostensible truth of their theories.*

> ***[Ostensive:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ostensive)***

> **1.** clearly or manifestly demonstrative.
> **2.** ostensible.

As far as I can tell, the only nuance between *ostensible* and *ostensive* is that *ostensible* means *evident* or *apparent*, sometimes *pretended* (externally), *ostensive* has a slight lean toward *certain* (internally).  However, *ostensive* is [not a widely used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ostensible%2Costensive&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Costensible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Costensive%3B%2Cc0) term, and is unlikely to be understood as different from *ostensible* in most contexts.  So *ostensible* takes the cake in point of usefulness.